# Simple HTTPS python server to detect weather its connected through ca-cert or not?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssl

first i create a ca-cert key pair with

```
openssl req -new -x509 -keyout private_key.pem -out public_cert.pem -days 365 -nodes
Generating a RSA private key
..+++++
.................................+++++
writing new private key to 'private_key.pem'
-----
You are about to be asked to enter information that will be incorporated
into your certificate request.
What you are about to enter is what is called a Distinguished Name or a DN.
There are quite a few fields but you can leave some blank
For some fields there will be a default value,
If you enter '.', the field will be left blank.
-----
Country Name (2 letter code) [AU]:.
State or Province Name (full name) [Some-State]:
Locality Name (eg, city) []:.
Organization Name (eg, company) [Internet Widgits Pty Ltd]:.
Organizational Unit Name (eg, section) []:.
Common Name (e.g. server FQDN or YOUR name) []:35.222.65.55 <----------------------- this ip should be server ip very important
Email Address []:
```

now i run a server with python code

```
# libraries needed: 
from http.server import HTTPServer, SimpleHTTPRequestHandler
import ssl , socket

# address set
server_ip = '0.0.0.0'
server_port = 3389

# configuring HTTP -> HTTPS
httpd = HTTPServer((server_ip, server_port), SimpleHTTPRequestHandler)
httpd.socket = ssl.wrap_socket(httpd.socket, certfile='./public_cert.pem',keyfile='./private_key.pem', server_side=True)
httpd.serve_forever()
```

now this server can be connected for both secure ca-cert case and ingore-ca-cert server connections when using SSL case

that is
`curl --cacert public_cert.pem --cert-type PEM   https://35.222.65.55:3389`
and
`curl -k https://35.222.65.55:3389`
will work

how to detect if the request is ingnore-ca-cert or not from server side ?

Comment: Both of those connections are secure.  They're both `https`.

Comment: @TimRoberts from curl perspective 
 -k, --insecure      Allow insecure server connections when using SSL

Comment: Works for me. Please add the `-v` option to curl and provide the output from the non-working version to show the exact error messages.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich i want it not to work for curl -k https://35.222.65.55:3389 option
is there any commands like ssl.CERT_REQUIRED code to make it strict

Comment: What you want is not possible. Apart from that it looks for me like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem), i.e. what is the real problem you want to solve? Is it that you only want clients to connect which know about the server certificate? It is that you want clients to accept a SSL intercepted connection? Or something else?

Comment: https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/4192/ssl.CERT_REQUIRED

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to communicate by posting this link without any context. If you feel that ssl.CERT_REQUIRED can be used for this - it can't. Given on the server side it is instead about enforcing client certificates which is something different. And no other setting is available too since as I said the server has no control over if and how the client validates the certificate.

Comment: `curl -k` is still a secure (meaning encrypted) connection.  It's just that the client doesn't validate the certificate used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how to not allow insecure connection from server side ?

The server side has no control over the certificate validation done at the client side. The server has no knowledge if the client has verified the certificate or not. Nothing in the exchanged data indicates if the client is doing a `curl -k` or a curl without this option. Thus it is not possible to stop clients with broken or disabled validation from connecting to the server.